# Is java.util.concurrent.Future threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to find documentation indicating if java.util.concurrent.Future is/is not threadsafe. Eg can I safely give the same instance of Future to multiple threads, which will all call Future.get(...)?

I have tested code using Future in this manner and it seems to work fine but I'd be much happier if I could find documented expectation that future is safe for concurrent access in this manner.

Thanks.

Comment: Essentially, this comment is the same as Nizet's answer: you can see memory consistency guarantees in JDK javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#package_description

Comment: Is it safe to read "Actions taken by the asynchronous computation represented by a Future happen-before actions subsequent to the retrieval of the result via Future.get() in another thread." as true for _many_ other threads as well as a single other thread? - "another thread" read literally indicates a **single** other thread as opposed to many. Ofc it seems likely a Future implementer would have to go out of their way to make it break for many and work for one so I strongly suspect this is safe in reality.

Comment: Yes, because each call to `Future.get()` will be under "happens-before" guarantee. It's because each call compiled to the same assembly involving one or another form of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier

Comment: Note that all threads will block waiting on the result of get(). And if the result of get() is mutable, all threads might not observe the same value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that Future is intended to be used by several threads (at least the one which submits, and the one which sets its result), and given that the documentation specifies that there is a happen-before relationship between the asynchronous computation and the actions occurring after the get call, I would assume that the implementations are thread-safe (at least the standard implementations).

Comment: I am strongly inclined to agree that it is almost certainly safe in reality given that thread-safety for happen-before to work between 2 threads would typically also be fine for N threads, however I am not 100% clear on if I can interpret the happen-before as guaranteed for many threads when the wording of the guarantee suggests a single other thread. Despite that minor reservation I am voting up your comment as it seems likely to be the best answer available.

Comment: @S42 You are reading the wording too literally.  In Java, there is absolutely no special communication between a pair of threads; all threads communicate by synchronizing the memory, and it is equally available to all threads.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a  `Future` returned from an `ExecutorService`, then yes they are guaranteed to be thread-safe.  Since Future is an interface, the creator of the interface cannot guarantee that all implementations would be thread-safe though.

Nizet does bring up a good point though.  The doc's say that implementations of the Future interface should be thread safe, not making the implementation thread-safe would then violate the Future's contract